# Altium: Duplicated instances of sheet symbols to create single PCB room

Tags: pcb, altium, symbol, port

I'm wondering if the following is possible in Altium:  To make my schematic easier to follow, I want to break up my sheet symbols into several different ones in the top level schematic, while not duplicating the PCB components.

For example, the "MCU" sheet in the schematic is used in multiple places wherever a microcontroller connects to a subsystem, but only a few of the ports are connected in each instance.  [image]

Comment: What you're describing sounds much like a [bus](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/schematic-bus?version=19.1) containing all MCU signals.

Comment: "The individual nets must be named using the standard naming pattern <Name><NumericalIdentifer1>, <Name><NumericalIdentifer2>, for example Address0, Address1, ..., Address n." -- This could work, but I'd definitely like for them to have unique net names

Comment: Turn it upside down: have everything else connect (in multiples, but solve it in such a way that no semantic duplicates are needed) to one master MCU sheet symbol. You can't have partials of sheet symbols like you can have multi-part Parts, which it sounds like the kind of thing you're going for. Alternately, consider using a Harness.

Comment: A harness works nicely!  Thanks for the tip.